# Converting html text to plain text in java using jericho, but in UI links are displaying like a plain text

Tags: java, jquery, html

while fetching an email am converting html text to plain text by using jericho renderer.
example input will be encoded in anchor tags, while parsing it will remove all hyperlinks and the output will be like this http://www.google.com.
but the problem is how can i display this as a link in UI. Can anyone tell me, what is the efficient way to handle this.

Comment: yes that is what ``anchor`` tags are for. See this http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

Comment: In UI links displaying like plain text, because "anchor tag" and "href" is removed from the link. But again i want to convert that plain text as link. Am using jquery and html5

Comment: How can i convert that to link

Comment: Can you create a minimal example, a fiddle, snippet may be to show the problem.